# .htaccess Rewrite without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site that's coded mainly in PHP, but I'm trying to rewrite my dynamic php URL's into static HTML URL's.

But I want the address bar to still remain as the static HTML link.

I'm trying to accomplish this through .htaccess (I have no access to httpd.conf as I'm hosted on a shared account). Here is what's written in my .httaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^inventory-search-([^.]+)-by-([^.]+).html$ http://www.pianostudiosandshowcase.com/inventory.php?search=$1&by=$2 [R]
```

But I can't get the address bar to remain as the static HTML link.

Here is a link to show you what I mean:

```
http://www.pianostudiosandshowcase.com/inventory.php?search=manufacturer&by=1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove both the `R` flag in your rewrite rule as well as the protocol/domain name:

```
RewriteRule ^inventory-search-([^.]+)-by-([^.]+).html$ /inventory.php?search=$1&by=$2 [L]
```

Both will cause the server to externally redirect the browser, telling it "what you were looking for is not at that URL, you need to go to this entirely different URL". The forces the browser to display the new location in its address bar.

If you internally rewrite it, the browser has no idea the URI that it sent as a request had been changed, therefore the address bar remains unchanged.